# is possible use Loadbalancer at Orocomerce with SSL?

Tags: amazon-elb, orocommerce

I have try use Application at load balancers but always because of url of Loadbalancer application have personal routing and not work with balancers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible use Oro Commerce with loadbalancer.
You should setup Application Load Balancer, upload certificates for your domain. Configure Application URL in Application Settings.

Comment: I have try, but not work! other App normal but Orocommerce no! Because have a router in-app configuration I think? And in final Loadbalancer creat a DNS different of router url create in application

Comment: It would be more productive if you show what error you have. Instead of asking questions in general terms.

Comment: @viachelasv has no error, but when control panel of admin, I change IP for route application to a domain name using HTTPS or HTTP, just not work.